# Batch with conditions cannot span multiple partitions

Tags: cassandra

I am using gocql, but it should make no different.
Do you know how to solve the following?:

```
A2B := gocql.NewBatch(gocql.LoggedBatch)
stmtA2B := "INSERT INTO tableName (idA, idB) VALUES (?,?) IF NOT EXISTS"

for index, id := range listOfids {
    A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "test_id_B") // This works
    A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_B", "test_id_A") // When I add this I get err
}

err := session.ExecuteBatch(A2B)
```

the error message is:

Batch with conditions cannot span multiple partitions
2015/11/05 19:30:04 http: panic serving x.x.x.x:44647: Batch with conditions cannot span multiple partitions

Comment: Can you post the error message that you're seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, batch statements cannot be run across multiple partitions.

I am assuming that idA is the partition key for your table. In that case, you will only be able to execute statements which are updating rows with the same value for idA. 
e.g. the below queries are fine in the same batch statement.

```
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "val1") 
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "val2") 
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "val3")
```

But not the following because rows for test_id_B are in a different partition to test_id_A

```
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "val1") 
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_A", "val2") 
A2B.Query(stmtAB, "test_id_B", "val3")
```